# I can't include ' symbol to Regular Expressions

Tags: swift, string, ios11, swift4

I try to include ' symbol to Regular Expressions

I use this function

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            text.substring(with: Range($0.range, in: text)!)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

and this Regular Expressions

```
    let matched = matches(for: "^[‘]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z]+$", in: string)
```

when I search I can find numbers and english letters

but not **'** symbol

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service

Comment: In your regular expession you have `‘` (left, single quotation mark). In you text, you have `'` (apostrophe). Can you spot the difference? Also, I believe you should have parenthesis around your expression otherwise that `+` is only for the `[a-zA-Z]` group.

Comment: @Sulthan I tried both ' and ‘ 
both doesn't work

Comment: Show your text that is not matched.

Comment: @Sulthan

`'cos
'tude
'twas
 'tween`

then I try to change it to

`  ‘cos
‘tude
‘twas
‘tween`

because I notice on iOS keyboard there is **‘** not **'**

but both doesn’t work 

as you can see it stat with symbol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that what you really want is this:

```
"['0-9a-zA-Z]+"
```

Note that I have removed the `^` (text start) and `$` (text end) characters because then your whole text would have to match.

I have merged the groups because otherwise you would not match the text as a whole word. You would get separate apostrophe and then the word.

I have changed the `‘` character into the proper `'` character. The automatic conversion from the simple apostrophe is caused by iOS 11 Smart Punctuation. You can turn it off on an input using:

```
input.smartQuotesType = .no
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2865931-smartquotestype

Comment: your code is working when I change keyboard to Arabic language on iPhone
and then use the apostrophe symbol on it , but if I use apostrophe symbol on English Keyboard 
it doesn't recognized it

Comment: @Basil You probably have some autocorrection turned on. If you have problems, just use both characters.

Comment: Thank your for your time , Exactly as you said ,when I turn Off 
**Smart Punctuation** 
it recognized ' on English keyboard

can I turn it of on my application ? , because I don't no about users if they are turn **Smart Punctuation** on

Comment: @Basil Didn't realize there is something like that in iOS 11, updated my answer, you can really turn it off.

Comment: Thank you for providing inputs for iOS 11 Smart Punctuation marks, it help me. :)

Comment: There is alse a `smartDashesType` setting.
`Use this property to configure whether UIKit converts two hyphens into an en-dash and three hyphens into an em-dash automatically. The default value of this property is UITextSmartDashesType.default, which selectively enables smart dashes based on the keyboard type.`